# Show Menu Option Automatically At First Activity Of Application

Tags: android

I develop a application

and in which i have a Menu option which i invoke from onCreateOptionMenu()

But this is called only when any user press the menu button

so now i want that my application start and first Activity is Welcome.java

then in onCreate(Bundle b)

can i write sone line from which the menu is invoked automatically without pressing Menu button

i used openOptionMenu() but it not works.

2) can i create a Button and simulate it as Menu button and then write button.performClick() so it act as a Menu Button and menu option will visible

So give me some suggestion on this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request the menu be opened with an [Activity method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29)

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

If you want to show a menu immediately, you'll have to wait for the window focus to change, rather than using onResume:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocusFlag) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocusFlag);       
    if (hasFocusFlag) {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows error, unable to add window token null is not valid, is your activity runnig? while my activity is running properly without this line

Comment: yes i try both, first in onCreate() and then in onResume() but error occur, Application Stops Unexpectedly, without visible

Comment: It seems that openOptionsMenu() does work once the window has been initialised but in onResume, the window is not ready. See my edit above.

Comment: Yes, since 1.0 in fact :) All methods are API level 1.

Comment: BEWARE! Doing `openOptionsMenu` in `onWindowFocusChanged` breaks the Back button: you'll get stuck on the screen with the menu! (Checked on  Gingerbread, not sure about later versions.)

Answer (score 1):

See [`openOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29)

Comment: it shows error, unable to add window token null is not valid, is your activity runnig? while my activity is running properly without this line

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will like to provide answer for your question

(" can i create a Button and simulate it as Menu button and then write button.performClick() so it act as a Menu Button and menu option will visible")

Answer:

**Step 1**-Create a button/ image button in your layout

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/a"
    android:onClick="expand"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />
```

Here I have set onClick method as "expand"

**Step 2**-Now in your MainActivity.java class define your "expand" method which will be call once user click on your button

```
public void expand(View v)
{
 ImageButton imgButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1) ;
 imgButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 openOptionsMenu();

}
```

In this code I have set visibility as "gone", as I want the button to disappear once menu is shown

**Step 3**-**(In case you are setting visibility for the button)** You can also write code to set visibility as "visible" once menu is closed using below method

```
   public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
    ImageButton imgButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1)  ;
    imgButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Hope this will help you.....